# Poor SSL performance with vsftpd

Tags: ssl, ftp, openssl, vsftpd, multi-threading

I'm trying to tweak vsftpd to achieve maximum performance for my usage:

- I have only one or two clients that connect to the server.
- File size is between ~15MB and 1GB.
- Typical transfer batch represent between 1 and 2GB of data.

For testing purposes, I'm using a tmpfs on both sides (thus eliminating any disks bottleneck) with a single 1GB file.

When SSL is disabled, performance is good, with a transfer rate at ~120MB/s (reaching the limits of gigabit networking).

With SSL enabled only for control traffic (and not data traffic), performance drops at about 112MB/s, which is still within the acceptable limits.

However, when SSL is enabled for data flows, the transfer speed drops dramatically:

- 6.7MB/s using 3DES & SHA (`ssl_ciphers=DES-CBC3-SHA` in vsftpd.conf)
- 16MB/s using DES & SHA (`ssl_ciphers=DES-CBC-SHA`)

I didn't tested other ciphers, but from what I can see from the CPU usage during the transfer, it seems that vsftpd is only using a single cpu/core per client. While this can fit for large ftp sites with hundreds of clients, I'd like to avoid this behavior and use more ressources on the server.

On a side note, if you have any ideas regarding other openssl ciphers...

Comment: Try the RC4-MD5 cipher. Seems to be a good balance of performance & security.

Comment: @HTTP500: indeed, way much better. 75MB/s average, albeit still using only 1 core.

Answer (score 2):

I just read http://unhandledexpression.com/2013/01/25/5-easy-tips-to-accelerate-ssl/ which suggests to run `openssl speed`. Depending on the results, you might want to pick another algorithm. Sadly, I have no idea how to spread the load of one encryption task to several cores.

Comment: Indeed. I'm using RC4-MD5, but still looking for the solution.